# Query to get unique (last in timeline) connection between 2 ids in a table

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table "messages" that
you can see the following image:
[image: table messages]

from this table **my id as user is 2**.
*Sometimes I am sender, sometimes I am receiver.*

I need a query that returns **only the last message** I exchange **from each user**. No matter if I sent it, or I received it.
I am not sure if I should use distinct here. I don't really know how to use it.

To be more understood, in the above table for example should return:

row with id=4   (the last message I had with user 4)
row with id=6   (the last message I had with user 1)
row with id=7   (the last message I had with user 3)
row with id=5   (the last message I had with user 7)
row with id=19  (the last message I had with user 15)

Comment: Can you provide the table dump or sqlfiddle of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM messages
    WHERE 2 IN (receiver_id, sender_id) -- useless if the table really only contains messages between you and another person
    GROUP BY IF(receiver_id = 2, sender_id, receiver_id) -- GROUP BY either sender_id or receiver_id, depending on which end of the exchange you are (will perform very poorly)
) AS last_message USING (id)
```

Further to knittl's comment, the above assumes a monotonically increasing `id` (such as an `auto_increment` column). If it is not the case, then you have to resort to something as ugly as this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(datetime) AS datetime, IF(receiver_id = 2, sender_id, receiver_id) AS other_id
    FROM messages
    WHERE 2 IN (receiver_id, sender_id)
    GROUP BY other_id
) AS last_message ON
    last_message.datetime = messages.datetime
    AND last_message.other_id = IF(receiver_id = 2, sender_id, receiver_id) -- this line is superfluous if only one message may be sent or received within one given second
```

Comment: Thank you!! I made a small change:
SELECT * FROM messages m
JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id) id
    FROM messages 
    WHERE 2 IN (receiver_id, sender_id) -- useless if the table really only contains messages between you and another person
    GROUP BY IF(receiver_id = 2, sender_id, receiver_id) -- GROUP BY either sender_id or receiver_id, depending on which end of the exchange you are (will perform very poorly)
) 

AS last_id on m.id = last_id.id

Comment: Selecting the maximum ID will only work if the IDs are incrementing with time (most likely they will, but good to know anyway)

Comment: Correct, I was too lazy to mention this :o) Second query added for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_id = 2 OR receiver_id = 2 ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
SELECT messages.*
FROM (
  SELECT receiver_id, sender_id, MAX(datetime) maxtime
  FROM messages
  WHERE receiver_id = 2
  OR sender_id = 2
  GROUP BY receiver_id, sender_id
) latest
LEFT JOIN messages
ON latest.receiver_id = messages.receiver_id
AND latest.sender_id = messages.sender_id
AND latest.maxtime = messages.datetime
```

([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d233/2/0))

Comment: Should you have two messages at the same time (depending on the resolution of your datetime column) you will get both messages.